# JavaScript assignment of primitive is not equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-class (from angularjs) to assign a class to the active page number in a paginated table.  When the "skip 10 pages" button is pressed it calls a function and ultimately ends up here:

```
if (this.scope.currentPage <= this.scope.lastPage - this.scope.pageNumbersGroupSize) {
    this.scope.currentPage += this.scope.pageNumbersGroupSize;
} else {
    while (this.scope.currentPage < this.scope.lastPage) {
        this.scope.currentPage++;
    }
    //this.scope.currentPage = this.scope.lastPage;
}
```

The code in the original if statement works as expected, but the code in the else does not.  Originally I only had the line which is commented out in the else statement:

```
this.scope.currentPage = this.scope.lastPage;
```

but for some reason it did not activate the class in my HTML:

```
<a ng-class="{'selectedPage' : pageNumber === currentPage, 'grayText' :
pageNumber !== currentPage}" ng-repeat="pageNumber in pageNumbers"
style="margin-right: 4px; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="goToPage(pageNumber)">
{{pageNumber}}
</a>
```

In the html when the pageNumber === currentPage, the class selectedPage should be used.  It isn't in the original code.  Then, just to check if the assignment wasn't the same reference for some reason I used:

```
this.scope.currentPage = angular.copy(this.scope.lastPage);
```

this still didn't work.  So, I tried the while loop which is in the code at the top now.  This does work.  Can someone explain why my original code doesn't work? Also, is there a better way to fix this issue than putting that while loop in there?   Thank you!

Comment: all those this. in your code sound weird, are you referencing you Ctrl with the ControllerAs syntax? http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: No, I'm using typescript and putting all of my functions outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out: it was because I was using a === instead of a == and the variable I was using for lastPage was coming back from the database stored procedure as a string instead of a number.  It was comparing a string to a number with === and they are not equal.  I just used parseInt() on the value returned from the DB and it is fixed.